# Can I use += on multiple variables on one line?

Tags: python, variables, reference, addition, augmented-assignment

While shortening my code I was cutting down a few variable declarations onto one line-

```
##For example- going from-
Var1 =15
Var2 = 26
Var3 = 922

##To-
Var1, Var2, Var3 = 15, 26, 922
```

However, when I tried doing the same thing to this code-

```
User_Input += Master_Key[Input_ref]
Key += Master_Key[Key_ref]
Key2 += Master_Key[Key_2_Ref]

##Which looks like-
User_Input, Key, Key2 += Master_Key[Input_Ref], Master_Key[Key_Ref], Master_Key[Key_2_Ref]
```

This throws the error

```
SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment
```

I have read the [relevant Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html), but I still can't find a way to shorten this particular bit of code.

Comment: Why does it need shortening? It's more straightforward and readable in the original form.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily, I was just trying to see if there was a simpler way to do it. When each line is basically adding a character to a string.For further information, this bit of the program is generating a random Input, Key and another Key for testing an encryption program. It does this using a for loop which picks a random number and references it against a string.

Comment: ' def Random_Test_Algorithm(Input_Length, Repeat_times):
    for i in range(Repeat_times): 
        User_Input, Key, Key2 = "", "", ""
        for i in range(Input_Length):
            Input_ref, Key_ref, Key_2_Ref = random.randint(0, len(Master_Key)-1), random.randint(0, (len(Master_Key)-1)), random.randint(0, (len(Master_Key)-1)) 
            User_Input += Master_Key[Input_ref]
            Key += Master_Key[Key_ref]
            Key2 += Master_Key[Key_2_Ref] '

Comment: How do I format that as code? It says ' code ' which didn't do anything

Comment: You can't format as blocks of code in comments. Only inline snippets by surrouding the text with ` characters (backticks not apostrophes). Add any relevant code to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python augmenting multiple variables inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132687/python-augmenting-multiple-variables-inline)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot. You cannot use augmented assignment together with multiple targets.

You can see this in the [*Augmented assignment statements* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) you linked to:

> ```
> augmented_assignment_stmt ::=  augtarget augop (expression_list | yield_expression)
> augtarget                 ::=  identifier | attributeref | subscription | slicing
> ```

The `augtarget` rule only allows for *one target*. Compare this with the [*Assignment statements* rules](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> ```
> assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)
> target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
> target          ::=  identifier
>                      | "(" target_list ")"
>                      | "[" target_list "]"
>                      | attributeref
>                      | subscription
>                      | slicing
> ```

where you have a `target_list` rule to assign to.

I'd not try and shorten this at all; trying to squeeze augmented assignments onto one line does *not* improve readability or comprehension of what is happening.

Comment: OK thanks. I wasn't really considering readability as it was just a personal little project.  However I have a question, what is actually more efficient? Will a, b, c = 1, 2, 3 actually execute faster?

Comment: @TheoPearson-Bray: The difference is not worh caring about, but tuple assignment with 3 elements executes *two* more bytecodes than direct assignment would. See [How does swapping of members in the python tuples (a,b)=(b,a) work internally?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21047622). Don't optimise for that tiny difference however.