# Add multiple return values to multiple variables in Python

Tags: python

## Assigning

I'm new in Python but I've already learned that assigning and returning multiple values is possible with the so called tuples.

**Assign multiple values at once**

```
> a, b = 1, 2
> a
1
> b
2
```

**Return multiple values**

```
> def f():
>   return 3, 4
>
> f()
(3, 4)
```

**Both combined also works**

```
> c, d = f()
> c
3
> d
4
```

---

## Adding

To implicitly add a return value to a variable the overloaded operator `+=` (`iadd`) can be used.

**Add operator `+=` (respectively called `iadd`)**

```
> e = 5
> e += 5
> e
10
```

**Works also with functions**

```
> def g():
>   return 10
>
> e += g()
> e
20
```

---

## Questions

Am I right, that the above mentioned behaviours can't be used together?
I tried the following snippet but it didn't work for me.

```
> x, y = 1, 2
> x, y += 3, 4
SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment

> def z():
>   return 10, 100
> x, y += z()
SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment
```

Until now Python was really intuative. That's why I thought approach would work out of the box.

Why isn't the `+=` operator overloaded for tuples? Wouldn't that make sense to keep Python as simple as it tries to be?

I found two approaches to solve this "problem" (using `x`, `y`, `z()` from above):

```
> import operator
> t = x, y
> tuple(map(operator.add, t, z()))
```

or to keep it simple (using `x`, `y`, `z()` from above):

```
> x1, y1 = z()
> x += x1
> y += y1
```

Are there better or even more intuitive approaches besides the ones that I mentioned?

Comment: _Why isn't the += operator overloaded for tuples?_ Tuples are immutable, _adding_ anything to tuple does not make much sense.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski But neither `x` nor `y` is a tuple so which is the tuple here that we are trying to mutate?

Comment: `+=` for `tuples` would mean to do something like extrapolation i.e. sum of sum form, I guess that is what the result you are expecting if `Python` treats this a legal expression.

Comment: [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132687/python-augmenting-multiple-variables-inline) has more info on augmented assignment

Comment: As far as the **philosophical** answer to this question: it would create an asymmetry between tuples and lists. The `+=` operator already has meaning for lists: it extends them. If `+=` performed element-wise addition for tuples, the behavior would be asymmetric with lists—which should only differ from tuples in their mutability.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Strings a immutable, too (at least in Java, which is what I learned first)! They have the `+` operator overloaded which just creates a new immutable object.
Furthermore only the tuple at the right side of the `+=` is immutable, the variables on the left side aren't.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct and you can't use those methods together, here is why (from my knowledge):

The way Python works when you use `=` operator is it calculates all expressions on the right side of the `=` and then it applies it to the left side (This is why you can do the multi-assignment trick. For more information on this read about packing and unpacking in python).

When you use the `+=` operator it calls the `__iadd__` method on the object on the left side with the right side expression evaluated as an argument. Since you can't 'iadd' stuff to a tuple but only to mutable objects (read about mutable and immutable in python) this operation is not legal.

What you thought the operation of `x, y += x1, y1` should do is what the `map` function does: It does the operation on each element one by one.
The other solution you showed is the way I would do this. This is also good if you need `z()`'s results afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I like **list-comprehensions**. Learning python, this would definitely be something for you to look into:

```
def add_for_all(sum1, sum2):
  return [j+sum2[i] for i,j in enumerate(sum1)]

wx = [1,2]
yz = [3,4]

print (add_for_all(wx, yz))
```

Comment: fair enough but I doubt this question is about how you can do it but rather as to why it does not work the way OP is trying to do it.

Comment: I see. Somehow the sentence containing the question mark (e.g. "Are there better or even more intuitive approaches besides the ones that I mentioned?") encouraged me to put in my 5 cents ;)

Comment: List-comprehensions are really useful and this is one of the many things that I love about Python!
But it seems to me a little bit overdone for my specific use case. But you're right: this is another working approach!