# Increment a few variables together

Tags: python, python-3.x

This might be a silly question but I couldn't figure it out. I have a function that returns 4 values. I want to add them to 4 variables I already have. Can I do it with `+=` in one line of code? Cause I get a syntax error now and I don't want to define 4 temp variables just to do the addition.

I'v tried this code:

```
def some_func():
        return a,b,c,d
a1,b1,c1,d1+=some_func()
```

I get this error: `illegal expression for augmented assignment`

How can I get around that?

Comment: dupe: [Python augmenting multiple variables inline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18132687/674039)

Comment: This suggests using a class that wraps the four variables and defines its own `__add__` and `__iadd__` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
a1, a2, a3, a4 = list(map(sum, zip([a1, a2, a3, a4], some_func())))
```

Full example

```
def some_func():
    return 1, 2, 3, 4


a1, a2, a3, a4 = 1, 2, 3, 4

a1, a2, a3, a4 = list(map(sum, zip([a1, a2, a3, a4], some_func())))

print(a1, a2, a3, a4)
```

Using the higher-order functions `map` and `zip`.

First the `zip` function, `zip([a1, a2, a3, a4], some_func())`, takes the values returned by `some_func()` and the existing values of `[a1, a2, a3, a4]` and creates a tuple between them (`(1, 1), (2, 2) ...`). Then using the higher-order function `map` and given the function `sum` and the list of tuples generated by `zip` is applying the function `sum` on the pairs. We then extract the result (which is a list) to the variables `a1, a2, a3, a4`.

Output:

```
2 4 6 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe you'll be able to do it in that specific way.

You could instead return a dictionary from your function, with your current variables (a, b, c) being treated as keys with there corresponding values grouped in. This could then be accessed and bound to the variables you'd like later on :)