# Is there an easy/native way to increment multiple values at once in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to do this:

```
def ret():
    return 1, 1

a, b = 1, 1
a, b += ret()

print(a, b)

>>> 2, 2
```

And if you want to concentrate it even further, just:

```
a, b = 1, 1
a, b += 1, 1
```

Of course this gives an error:

> SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment

Is there any native way to do this?

Comment: I think you mean `increment` instead of `iterate` in the question topic?

Comment: What's wrong with doing `res = ret()` and then separately: `a += res[0]` and `b+=res[1]`?

Comment: @BramDekker yes I always do that and it always feels slightly annoying. I thought I'd ask

Comment: Consider whether you are using the most appropriate data types. `a = numpy.array([1,1]); a += 1; asset numpy.all(a == numpy.array([2,2]))`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no syntactic sugar for this.
However, you can easily define a function to do this:

```
import operator


def multi_update(init, update, op=operator.iadd):
    return (op(x, y) for x, y in zip(init, update))


a, b = 1, 1
a, b = multi_update((a, b), (1, 1))
print(a, b)
# 2 2
```

Comment: You *could*, but can you really tell me with a straight face that you would prefer this to `a += 1; b += 1`?

Comment: @chepner No. But I can tell you I might prefer it on `a, b, c, d, e, ...` or something similar. But then again a good-old `list` may be better.

Comment: Also, for types that *do* support in-place modification, this is not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot provide augmented assignment on multiple variables at once.

Please read this solution:

[Python augmenting multiple variables inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132687/python-augmenting-multiple-variables-inline)